# How to use the Dropbox folder as the document root for Apache

Tags: apache, dropbox, virtualbox, web-testing

I recently installed Windows 7 Ultimate on Virtualbox to test my web projects with IE, etc. Instead of shared folders I use Dropbox for having the same document root in my Host OS (Ubuntu 12.04) and my Guest OS (it's because I test also on another machine).

I already changed the document root to the right folder, but when i want to acess localhost, it gives me erorr code 403, because Apache can't acess to that folder

My question now: How can I change permissions for that folder in Ubuntu and Windows to let Apache acess to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**Accessing From Ubuntu**

*CHMOD -R 777 /your/directory/* (or 755) would be an easy way to just give access to everyone or you can use *chown -R apache:apache /your/directory/* <-- may need to ensure the user is actually known as 'Apache'... try the CHMOD bit first and see if it works.

**Accessing From Windows**

I really don't think there'd be a problem on this side of the fence at all unless Ubuntu is halting it from accessing it somehow? If so, the CHMOD -R 777 above may effectively fix this.